# Sending data from NodeJS without re-rendering the whole page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written a pretty trivial Express NodeJS application which reads data from the user in the form and sends to the server. The server does some manipulations and returns a new string to the same page. However for returning the new data to the currently loaded page, I have to re-render the page. I want to just update a string by sending it from node js and not re-rendering the whole page.

I have the following questions:

- How to send data from NodeJS server *without re-rendering* the whole page?
- Why does sending data with `Post` method, provides data in `req.body.XXX` but sending data with `Get` method, returns `undefined` for `req.body.XXX`.

  ```
   <html>
     <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1><%= title %></h1>
      <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

      <form id="myForm" action = "http://localhost:3000/testing" method="post"> 
        Enter Url: <input type="text" name="urlEditText"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        Shortened Url:<%= shortenedUrl %> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
       </form>
      </body>
   </html>
  ```

**index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', shortenedUrl: ''});
    console.log("hello inside index.js method 0");
});


// passing an updated string back to the page
router.post('/yolo', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'NewTitle', shortenedUrl: req.body.urlEditText});
    console.log("hello inside index.js method 1");
});
```

***EDIT:***

**JQuery script for submission:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").bind('click', function() {

      event.preventDefault();
      $("#myForm").submit(function() {
         document.write("button clicked calling yolo script");
      });

      $.post('/yolo', function() {
        document.write("button clicked calling yolo script");
        alert("yolo");
      });

    });
```

Comment: Aren't you just looking for regular ajax ?

Comment: Also, for `GET` requests, the data is in `req.query`

Comment: try adding socket.io to your application. It provides easiest way to send data to client without multiple requests from client.

Comment: @adeneo Forgive my illiteracy in web development but I think ajax is for client side. So how can I use ajax to send data from Server to the client?

Comment: You're submitting data from a form to the server, the server does something with the data and returns it in a new page. This is where ajax comes in, it's the exact use case it was intended for, sending data from the client, returning data to that request etc. Or do you need to randomly push data from the server to the client without the client asking for it.

Comment: actually Client presses a Submit button and the server returns a new String back to the client. For returning the data, I am using router.render() method. Is there anyother method which will return data without re-rendering the page?

Comment: Yes, just use ajax to submit the form, it's straight forward, but it has to be done on the clientside, the server can't determine wether or not to load a page, only the browser can

Comment: So now I'll have learn Ajax too :P I have just started learning NodeJS Express.

Comment: A good tip would be to start with jQuery, it makes ajax a lot easier, and if you don't want to use jQuery, replace it with `XMLHttpRequest` when you get how it works.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. For now I am more interested in Server side development & especially Node as it's HOT now a days. It will help me alot in Android/iOS development too. :)

Comment: Understanding ajax is always HOT, as it's the general way to make things update without reloading the page. Ajax is done just as a form submit, the client sends data, and gets data back. Sockets are great as well, but mostly for two way communication with the server, for example when pushing updates, stock prices etc. to the client whenever there is a change, without the client having to ask for the data, like you would have to with ajax.

Comment: @adeneo I have looked up an ajax tutorial, it requires a url for the server. As far as I know, Node takes care of calling the required script file based on the action tag. What will I do in the case of AJAX? Can you provide a little example?

Comment: You just call the route you want, like `$.post('/yolo', function(data) {...` in jQuery would call your `/yolo` route and return whatever it outputs as `data`.

Comment: @adeneo how do I get the data on the nodejs side? I have tried `req.body.editText` but it returns empty

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using something like socket.io so you can send and receive data from the server without reloading the page. Here is a simple example from their site:

Server (app.js)

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client (index.html)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

`res.render` is used only to render a page. In your case you most probably need `res.json({title: 'newTitle', ...})`

As for your second question, `req.body` is only populated with data for `POST` and `PUT` requests. For `GET` you can rely on `req.query` or `req.params` depending how your organize your API routes

Comment: The second argument is probably for templating, like EJS, and has nothing to do with JSON ?

Comment: He wants to update the string without re-rendering the page, hence the ajax request needs to be made and response should be done in form of JSON(or other format). He didn't ask about `ajax`, he asked how to send data back from SERVER

Comment: And `res.render` sends data back the exact same way as `res.json`, the latter only adds a set of headers and stringifies objects, but the object you're seeing is used for templating, it's transfered to the template etc. When doing same-origin ajax calls, it doesn't matter what you return, JSON is a great data format, but it could just as well be HTML or chinese poems.